# How to make Grid items horizontally center using tailwind CSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I want to make the child `div`s horizontally centered in the same row. Both child `div`s have 2 column space each, which means there will be 4 columns-worth of space on the left and right side.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="grid bg-gray-100 gap-2">
  <div class="bg-red-200 p-5">child div with 2cols width 01</div>
  <div class="bg-green-200 p-5">child div with 2cols width 02</div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Both child divs acquire 2 column space each that means it will leave 4 cols space a left and right side" I'm not sure how you came to this conclusion – they are both currently laid out vertically stacked at the moment.